# Intellij IDEA Hibernate Console not finding JDBC Driver

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, intellij-idea

I am trying to use the Hibernate Console to query my database.  My project is currently set up to use Hibernate.  However, whenever I try a simple query, I get an error saying that the JDBC Driver cannot be found.
[image]

I currently have mysql-connector on my classpath
[image]

I'm really not sure what else to do.  I think everything should be working, and it's not.  Does anyone have any advice?

**Edit**

I checked the Data Sources and Drivers and confirmed that Intellij knows where a MySQL driver is.  I know it works because I issued sql queries using the MySQL console.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the JDBC Driver class not found Exception. I right clicked on a sessionFactory and selected "Assign Data Sources". Then I selected the MySQL data source. Before it was "none". Now everything is working

[image]

Comment: Keeps resetting to "none" for me. No idea why. pretty annoying

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your secind screenshot is coming from the module settings, is that right? I don't think IntelliJ will use the project `.m2` when formulating internal dependencies/classpath details.

Do you have the database driver setup in the database widget (usually docked to the right hand side of IntelliJ)? From here you can setup your database connections, and download appropriate JDBC drivers.

Take this screenshot for example, IntelliJ has downloaded the MySQL Drivers and the are in `/Users/acanby/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea14/...`, not a maven `.m2` directory:

[image: Data Sources and Drivers]

I would expect IntelliJ to not know how to connect to MySQL databases until the appropriate driver is downloaded. Can you check to ensure it is downloaded? `Database widget > Data Sources and Drivers > Drivers > MySQL`. If it is not downloaded, download it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the mysql-connector-java-version-bin.jar file to your project, right click on it, select "Add as library".